# Can I reuse an Existing Connection String in my SQL Session State Config?

Tags: asp.net, web-config, connection-string, session-state

I'm using SQL Session State in my app, however given that we have several connection strings already, it would be easier to maintain the config if all the connection strings were held, well, in `<connectionStrings>`.

My question is, is it possible somehow to specify an existing connection string in the `sessionState` config?

```
   <connectionStrings>
        <add name="ConnString1" connectionString="data source=xx;Initial Catalog=zzz;"  
             providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
        <add name="EFConnString" 
             connectionString="metadata=res://*/EF.csdl|res://*/EF.ssdl|res://*/EF.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;data source=xxx;initial catalog=yyy;App=EntityFramework&quot;" 
             providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
        <add name="SessionStateConn" connectionString="data source=xx;Initial Catalog=zzz;"  
             providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
  </connectionStrings>
  <system.web>
    <sessionState mode="SQLServer" 
                  sqlConnectionString="**SessionStateConn**" 
                  sqlCommandTimeout="30" customProvider="" ... etc
    </sessionState>
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Anyone coming to this late the MSDN documentations state that for the sqlConnectionString attribute you can specify either the full connection string OR the name of an existing connection string:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h6bb9cz9%28v=vs.85%29.aspx
(see sqlConnectionString under Attributes & Elements)

Answer (score 4):

Not really. At least not in a straightforward way that does not require change in the code or transforming the configuration file. The reason behind this inconsistency in ASP.NET is that SQL Server session state was introduced in the original version of ASP.NET whereas the `connectionStrings` section was added in version 2.0. The `sessionState` tag designers could not rely on a system that had not been invented/shipped yet.

Comment: Thanks for the background on this!